# Delphi + iOS : How to translate this code to Delphi?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I try to translate header of FBAudienceNetwork.framework to Delphi

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FBNativeAdViewTag) {
    FBNativeAdViewTagIcon = 5,
    FBNativeAdViewTagTitle,
    FBNativeAdViewTagCoverImage,
    FBNativeAdViewTagSubtitle,
    FBNativeAdViewTagBody,
    FBNativeAdViewTagCallToAction,
    FBNativeAdViewTagSocialContext,
    FBNativeAdViewTagChoicesIcon,
    FBNativeAdViewTagMedia,
};

/**
 Use this category to set tags for views you are using for native ad.
 This will enable better analytics.
 */
@interface UIView (FBNativeAdViewTag)
@property (nonatomic, assign) FBNativeAdViewTag nativeAdViewTag;
@end
```

Delphi code

```
const
  FBNativeAdViewTagIcon = 5;
  FBNativeAdViewTagTitle = 6;
  FBNativeAdViewTagCoverImage = 7;
  FBNativeAdViewTagSubtitle = 8;
  FBNativeAdViewTagBody = 9;
  FBNativeAdViewTagCallToAction = 10;
  FBNativeAdViewTagSocialContext = 11;
  FBNativeAdViewTagChoicesIcon = 12;
  FBNativeAdViewTagMedia = 13;

type

FBNativeAdViewTag = NSUInteger;

FBNativeAdViewTag = interface(IObjectiveC)
    ['{F87149BD-3905-4566-B5B0-85F2C5ABB121}']
    procedure setNativeAdViewTag(nativeAdViewTag: FBNativeAdViewTag); cdecl;
    function nativeAdViewTag: FBNativeAdViewTag; cdecl;
  end;
```

I get error:

> Identifier redeclared 'FBNativeAdViewTag'

How to translate this code to Delphi?

Comment: Use an enumerated type for the enum. Do you understand the compiler error?

Comment: There's no such *delegate* as FBNativeAdViewTag in the framework, therefore your last declaration is unnecessary. A complete import can be found here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/API/DW.iOSapi.FBAudienceNetwork.pas